# PHP pthreads Notice Message

Tags: php, pthreads

When I try to run a PHP script with pthreads, I am getting the following errors, anyone know how to solve this issue? It does seem to be error message, and the operation seem to have ran.

This only happens during the execution of pthreads, nothing else.

```
Notice: Constant http\client\curl\HTTP_VERSION_1_0 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\HTTP_VERSION_1_1 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\HTTP_VERSION_ANY already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\SSL_VERSION_TLSv1 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\SSL_VERSION_SSLv2 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\SSL_VERSION_SSLv3 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\SSL_VERSION_ANY already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\IPRESOLVE_V4 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\IPRESOLVE_V6 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\IPRESOLVE_ANY already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\AUTH_BASIC already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\AUTH_DIGEST already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\AUTH_DIGEST_IE already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\AUTH_NTLM already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\AUTH_GSSNEG already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\AUTH_ANY already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\PROXY_SOCKS4 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\PROXY_SOCKS4A already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\PROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\PROXY_SOCKS5 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\PROXY_HTTP already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\PROXY_HTTP_1_0 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\POSTREDIR_301 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\POSTREDIR_302 already defined in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Constant http\client\curl\POSTREDIR_ALL already defined in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Also getting this. Only with php 5.4.45. with 5.6.15 don't get. Can't rule out its a configuration issue with my 5.4.45 install though.

Answer (score 0):

You are including a file in the thread which is trying to redefine constants already defined.

Comment: Nah. I'm getting it with this PHP `class T extends Thread{}; $t1 = new T(); $t1->start();`. Thread::start() is causing it.